# How with Flask-admin Enum field display value, not name?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have flask-sqlalchemy model with enum cloumn. I need to display enum.value on edit page, but store in db enum.name. I've tryed form_choices, it displays fine, but when edit page opened, vlue drops.

```
class TransmissionType(enum.Enum):
    MANUAL = 'Manual'
    AUTOMATIC = 'Automatic'
    ROBOT = 'Robot'
    VARIABLE = 'Variable'

class Car(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'car'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    transmission = db.Column('transmission', db.Enum(TransmissionType), nullable=False)

class CarModelView(BaseMV):
    form_choices = {
            'transmission': [
                ('MANUAL', 'Manual'),
                ('AUTOMATIC', 'Automatic'),
                ('ROBOT', 'Robot'),
                ('VARIABLE', 'Variable')
            ]}
```